# Bash -value too great for base (error token is "09") for date string yyyymmdd

Tags: bash, shell, date, radix

I am trying to generate a startDate in the format yyyymmdd such that this date is the 1st day of the third last month. For example, the current month is July (07), so I need to get my start date as the 1st day of April (04) - 20150401.

In order to achieve this in bash, I used the following command:

```
StartDate=$(date -d "-3 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +"%Y%m%d")
```

However, this is giving me the following error:

```
line 93: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

I do not want to change the format of the StartDate variable. For single digit months (1-9), the format should have a leading zero infront of the month number in the yyyymmdd format.

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EtanReisner yap, it's 10 here..

Comment: Incidentally, the factoid for this in the freenode bash channel is `!august`. Quote: "August is the month when all your scripts break because you placed $(date +%m) in a variable and tried to do arithmetic with it, without removing the leading zeros. 08 is considered octal. Use $((10#$month)) to force decimal, or strip the zero."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bash is seeing `09` and trying to treat it as an octal number which fails.

You can prefix the date value with `10#` to force a base. See the second-to-last paragraph of [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

```
StartDate=$(date -d "-3 month -$((10#$(date +%d)-1)) days" +"%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace `+%d` (zero padded day of month) by `+%e` (space padded) to avoid a leading zero.